# Failing To Display Username

Tags: php, html, mysqli

I am having a problem trying to display the username on the profile page from the $_GET, the session is created but unable to display the username on the profile page.

```
    <?php include("template/header.php");
include("requires/connection.php"); ?>

    <?php
    if(isset($_GET['u'])) {
        $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($_GET['u']);
        if(ctype_alnum($username)) {
         // Check user exists
          $check = mysqli_query("SELECT username FROM users WHERE username='$username'");
    if(mysqli_num_rows($check)===1) {
            $get = mysqli_fetch_assoc($check);
            $username = $get['username'];
          }
          else {
            echo "<h2>User doesn't exist</h2>";
            exit();
          }
        }
      }
    ?>

      <div class="profile-content-container">
         <h1>Profile <?php echo "$username"; ?></h1>
         <p>Welcome</p>    
      </div><!-- end of profile-content-container -->

      <div class="profileMenu">
            <div id="leftsideMenu">
              <ul>
                <li><a href="home.php">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="profile.php">My Profile</a></li>
                <li><a href="#"></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"></a></li>
                <li><a href="logout.php">Logout</a></li>
              </ul><!-- end of menu -->
            </div><!-- end of leftsideMenu -->
          </div><!-- end of profileMenu -->    
    <?php include("template/footer.php"); ?>
```

Comment: clue: pass db connection to functions. This isn't `MySQL_` - *"We're not in Kansas anymore"*

Comment: and who knows which MySQL API you're connecting with in the first place and if your GET array isn't failing.

Comment: Using the latest version of MySQL API.

Comment: You just did what is called a "Stealth" edit and using my suggestion in your edit without marking it as an edit. In turn, I stand at being downvoted for it, where people will say *"he's connecting, so why the answer?"*. I performed a rollback to a previous revision. Please don't do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both `mysqli_real_escape_string()` and `mysqli_query()` functions require that the DB connection be passed as the first parameter; yours doesn't have that.

```
mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_GET['u'])
                          ^^^^^ see that?
```

so...

```
$username = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_GET['u']);
                                      ^^^^^ add the db connection variable
```

and for the query

```
mysqli_query($con, "SELECT ...
             ^^^^^ see that?
```

I used `$con` here, because there is no indication as to which variable you are using to assign the connection to.

References:

- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php

Sidenote: You may want to change this

```
if(mysqli_num_rows($check)===1)
```

to

```
if(mysqli_num_rows($check) >0 )
```

where I seen in some case that `===1` failed.

Another thing, changing this block of code

```
$get = mysqli_fetch_assoc($check);
$username = $get['username'];
```

to, and using a `while` loop

```
while($get = mysqli_fetch_assoc($check)){
         // or mysqli_fetch_array

    $username = $get['username'];

}
```

Plus, your DB connection should be `mysqli_` based and not `mysql_` or PDO, which is also unknownst to us.

- Those different MySQL APIs do not intermix.

References:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php

---

Add `or die(mysqli_error($con))` to `mysqli_query()` to check for errors.

Add [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) to the top of your file(s) which will help find errors.

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// rest of your code
```

**Sidenote:** Displaying errors should only be done in staging, and never production.

---

Your code shows a GET array; without knowing where that is populated from, make sure it's set and not empty.

If using a form, then make sure that a POST method isn't implied.

If your form is using a POST method, then you should be using POST and not GET. Make sure the element has a "name" attribute, IF you're using form.

- Also unknownst to us.

Again, if you're using a form with a POST method, or whatever, make sure there is a name attribute for it.

I.e.:

```
<input type="text" name="u">
```

---

**Edit:**

This part will throw an undefined variable notice:

```
<h1>Profile <?php echo "$username"; ?></h1>
```

So, use a conditional statement for it:

```
<h1>Profile 
<?php
if(isset($username) && !empty($username)) {

    echo $username;
}

else{
    echo "Username is empty or not set somewhere.";
}

?>
</h1>
```

or use a [**ternary operator**](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php)

```
<h1>Profile <?php echo $username ? $username : ""; ?></h1>
```

or

```
<h1>Profile <?php echo $username ? $username : "It is empty"; ?></h1>
```

or

```
<h1>Profile <?php echo !empty($_GET['u']) ? $_GET['u'] : ""; ?></h1>
```

or

```
<h1>Profile <?php echo !empty($_GET['u']) ? $_GET['u'] : "It is empty."; ?></h1>
```

As you stated in comments, you are using `?u="username"` which should read without quotes `?u=username` or as an example `?u=john` no quotes and may be case sensitive. So `john` may not be the same as `John` with an uppercase "J".

Comment: I added my connection variable to those 2 lines but still not displaying the username. I use $con for the connection.

Comment: @Andy I've made a few edits since you first saw it and in regards to a possible use of a form. If that is the case, you need to post it. If you are using anything other for it to pass the GET array, I need to see how it's used. Usually it's something to the effect of `file.php?u` etc. Use error reporting as outlined in my answer and error checking on the query.

Comment: @Andy if you're using JS/Ajax and didn't post, then that needs to be shown. `$con` saying it's that, doesn't tell me much, not seeing how you're connecting.

Comment: I am getting a "Undefined variable: username" but I have defined it "$username = mysqli_real_escape_string($_GET['u']);" I am using mysqli and not mysql.

Comment: @Andy you're not still using `$username = mysqli_real_escape_string($_GET['u']);` - if so, you didn't read my answer. I need to know where GET is coming from. otherwise I cannot help you anymore than I already have and know already from what you posted.

Comment: The form is on another page of the website, the $_SESSION is created.

Comment: @Andy what does this have to do with sessions? I'm sorry Andy, but this thread just turned into "automatically move to chat", and I don't have time to "chat". If you're relying on sessions, then make sure the session has been started, mainly `session_start();`. Again... I have no idea where you are getting/using `GET['u']` from. I have done what I could. Sorry, but I can't work with code that I cannot see.

Comment: Ok, I know my problem but can't fix. When I type into the url ?u="username" it will show the username in the h1 tag that I want but without the ?u="username" in the url it won't display it. How can I fix this site that it is displayed in the h1 as well.

Comment: @Andy I made another edit, look near the bottom under **Edit:**

Comment: @Andy and `?u="username"` should read without quotes `?u=username` or as an example `?u=john` no quotes and may be case sensitive. So `john` may not be the same as `John` with an uppercase "J".

Comment: Sorry for not noting changes to the code, I am new to this site and I have been working on the problem for 2 weeks. The login form is POST. This issue is going to drive me insane.... The login form is on one page and the profile pages is another. I want to display the username of the person logged in on the profile page. In the <h1> tag. Sorry if I am annoying anybody..